# In Unity, how do I set up a delay before an action?

Tags: c#, unity, timer

I want an object to rotate after a delay. I tried using `StartCoroutine`, `yield` and `WaitForSeconds`, but failed. How can I do it?

Comment: If you have additional questions, you should ask them as [new questions](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), instead of editing one you've previously asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a variable for example called `timer` of type float and make it equal to the amount of seconds you would like to wait, then in the `Update()` function subtract `Time.deltaTime` from your `timer` variable. Afterwards use if statement to check if the `timer` variable is equal to zero, if so rotate the object.

Comment: I do not get errors anymore, but it still has no effect

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27492/discussion-on-answer-by-vadim-tatarnikov-how-can-i-set-up-a-delay-before-the-rot).

Answer (score 2):

Multiple choices, but you will have to use Coroutine sometimes, so try to figure out why its not working here.

My tips : careful to not call StartCoroutine in Update() without protection.

Exemple:

```
private bool enter = false;

Update() {
    if (enter == false)
        StartCoroutine(your_timer());
}

IEnumerator your_timer() {
    enter = true;
    Debug.Log("Your enter Coroutine at" + Time.time);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    enter = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)

```
public void Invoke(string methodName, float time);
```

> Invokes the method *methodName* in *time* seconds.

There is a restriction that the method needs to take no parameters and return `void`, so you should wrap your rotation in another function, like so:

```
void delayedRotation() {
    transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, 0, 1) * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

and then adjust your code:

```
if (isRolling) 
{
    transform.position += new Vector3 (0,1,2)
    Invoke("delayedRotation", 0.5f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update(){
    if(INSERT_CONDITION_HERE){


        StartCoroutine(Timer);
     }
}
```

Then

```
IEnumerator Timer(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time);
    CODEGOESHERE
}
```